# Is this proof of the measure zero property of a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove that the "infinite straight line" has Lebesgue measure zero as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

My approach is as follows. Let $\epsilon >0$ and let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ denote the set of all points constituting the straight line. We can cover $A$ by a decreasing sequence of rectangles $B_{k}$ each of width $\frac{1}{n}$ and length $\frac{1}{n^{2k+1}}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So the area of each rectangle is $\frac{1}{n^{2k}}$, and $A = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_{k}$. Now $\frac{1}{n^{2k}} < \epsilon^{2k}$ and so the total area of the rectangles is

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2k}} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \epsilon^{2k} = \frac{\epsilon^{2}}{1 - \epsilon^{2}} < \epsilon$.

Thus we covered $A$ with a countable infinity of rectangles whose total area is less than $\epsilon$ and we are done.

Is this correct?

Comment: I haven't checked the details but the _method_ is certainly correct.

Comment: If you are willing to use rotation and translation invariance of Lebesgue measure, then you could reduce to the case where the line is the $x$-axis, which would probably make the argument easier (i.e. you wouldn't have to take into account what the slope of the line is, and it would be easier to make things more explicit).

Comment: More generally, if $p<q$ are positive integers and $f:\mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R^q$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $K$ then $\lambda(f(\mathbb R^p))=0$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^q$. Here $p=1$, $q=2$, and $f(x) = (x,mx+b)$ for some constants $m$, $b$.

Comment: Yes, thanks - I'm aware of this fact; I just wanted to see whether the details of my simple construction are correct, or if I missed anything @Math1000

Comment: The main point which is suspicious is that you simply state "We can cover ...", Without indicating **why** this can be done.

Comment: Why don't you just use Fubini's Theorem. Every section of a line is a singleton so the result follows immediately.

Comment: Yes indeed that's what I was wondering about too. Intuitively, this can be done, despite the length of each rectangle shrinking to zero. But how do I justify this step rigorously? @PhoemueX